How to preserve the space of the status bar? (Android 15+)
Android 15 suggests to use enableEdgeToEdge(), but this removes the top offset of the status bar, causing the main content to overlap with it.
What is the best way to preserve the height of the status bar? Just leave it transparent and render contents below it.
This is my attempt, it works but it's a lot of code, is there any simpler way?
// in the MainActivity.onCreate():

enableEdgeToEdge()

// the callback will be invoked repeatedly, use this flag to only set the margin-top once
var offsetAdjusted = false

window.decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, insets ->
    if (!offsetAdjusted) {
        offsetAdjusted = true

        val top = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Def.ANDROID_10) // for android > 10
            insets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()).top
        else // for android 10
            view.rootWindowInsets.stableInsetTop

        // the fragment container, which is a FragmentContainerView
        val container = binding.root.findViewById<FragmentContainerView>(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)

        val params = container.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        params.topMargin = top
        container.layoutParams = params
    }

    insets
}


EDIT: Seems like there's a way to opt out of this as well temporarily. Not recommended but it's there
Using the flag windowOptOutEdgeToEdgeEnforcement which can be true/false
Description can be found here
There are many ways possible to do this
There is a flag called fitsSystemWindows which can be set to true in your AndroidManifest.xml if it's just the status bar ( the one on the top ) you're targeting. See here
Another approach, which is very similar to what you've done is using the setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
You can also return WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED if you consume it, so that it doesn't trigger the code repeatedly

ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.recyclerView) { v, insets ->
  val bars = insets.getInsets(
    WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()
      or WindowInsetsCompat.Type.displayCutout()
  )
  v.updatePadding(
    left = bars.left,
    top = bars.top,
    right = bars.right,
    bottom = bars.bottom,
  )
  WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
}


You can give the section here a read once as well
Hope this helps

The setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener doesn't work somehow, the second solution works perfectly, thanks.

Updated a third solution as well

With the setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener solution, when the padding is changed, the state bar becomes opaque, is it possible to preserve the padding and make the status bar transparent?

Nope, I think that's default Android 15 behaviour

@aj3423 In my opinion, the opaque status bar is either an Android bug or bad design. So I came up with a custom solution based on setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener. I posted it as a separate answer.

I made use of the ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener solution but I didn't like the side effect of the state bar becoming opaque. In my opinion, it's either an Android bug or bad design. So I came up with a custom solution based on ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener.
At the top of my layout, I added an empty view like this:
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/android15statusBarPlaceHolder"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@color/gray"/>

(The view is invisible by default as it's not needed on older Android versions.)
The idea behind the view is that it is placed where the status bar is, and the view's height is set to be equal to the height of the status bar. So the status bar gets its color from the view's android:background property. Or instead of android:background, you can use the style property to set different background for light and dark modes.
In my activity, I added this code for Android 15+:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.VANILLA_ICE_CREAM) {
    val placeHolder: View = parentView.findViewById(R.id.android15statusBarPlaceHolder)
    // make the view visible
    placeHolder.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(parentView) { v, insets ->
        val bars = insets.getInsets(
            WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()
                        or WindowInsetsCompat.Type.displayCutout()
        )
        // set status bar placeholder's height equal to that of the status bar
        placeHolder.updateLayoutParams {
            height = bars.top
        }
        v.updatePadding(
            left = bars.left,
            right = bars.right,
            bottom = bars.bottom
        )

        WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
    }
}

In my code, I use the updateLayoutParams function to set the empty view's height. With this approach, it is not needed to set the top padding. So I pass only three params to the updatePadding function: for left, right, and bottom padding.
